# What does "regularly" refer to in this?

Tags: adverbs, ambiguity, modifiers

Can anyone help me find out what "regularly" modifies in the following excerpt? (My emphasis)

> If we heard that an alien species had a word that could be meaningfully used to describe things as varied as the height of mountains, the speed of travel, the difficulty of games, the nutritional content of food, the reaction in a moment, the way we plan our day, the passage of a lifetime, and our relative success at publishing, we’d be in awe of their linguistic flexibility. But numbers actually can do all these things.
> Even people who work with numbers **regularly** forget this.
>
> — *Making Numbers Count: The Art and Science of Communicating Numbers,* Chip Heath, Karla Starr; Transworld 2022

Should *regularly* apply as "regularly forget this" or "work with numbers regularly"?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the grammar, but my guess is that the writer meant 'people who work with numbers regularly'. It could have been better expressed.

Comment: The beauty of adverbs is that they can [always] be omitted and, [thus], such problems disappear.

Comment: @Greybeard Not entirely, because you lose the detail they supply. Here, we know "people who work with numbers forget this", but we don't know whether that happens even with regular working or that they forget it regularly. It does seem you may know the answer here.

Comment: As has been pointed out, in principle the target of ***regularly*** is ambiguous. But logically I think it *must* be modifying ***forget*** - I see no sense in attempting to draw a distinction between people who *regularly* work with numbers and those who only *occasionally* work with numbers. The important point is ***they work with numbers*** - so the writer includes the word ***even*** because he thinks all people professionally dealing with numbers should be ***constantly*** in awe of how versatile numbers are (they shouldn't keep forgetting this).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  - Funny - I interpret it the other way, as mentioned above. "Even the most mathematically-minded of people (as opposed to those who only need to do sums occasionally) sometimes forget it."

Comment: That gives the same result whichever way you parse it. A semantic saddle-point.

Comment: @KateBunting: I took on board the *first* assertion in your original comment, but somehow I failed to read the rest properly - I just assumed it reflected my own thoughts the same as the first assertion. Well, at least we definitely agree it's ambiguous! But is it possible the OP's highlighting misled you into "hearing" (assuming you internally "hear" text as you read it, which I know I do) heavy stress on the actual word ***regularly***? I read it with stress on the word ***work*** - because initial ***even*** put me on alert to seek the first credible word being emphasized in following text.

Comment: If we intended to modify *work*, we would probably choose the more idiomatic construction of *Even people who regularly work with numbers forget this.*

Comment: @KateBunting I'm with FumbleFingers. Everyone works with numbers sometime, so calling out "people who work with numbers" as a group must mean people who do so frequently. Adding "regularly" would be redundant. On the other hand, the fact that these people regularly forget an important feature of numbers is the surprising fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's modifying "forget this".

If we describe a group of people as "people who work with numbers", the implication is that they work with numbers regularly, since practically everyone works with numbers occasionally. If it modified "people who work with numbers", it would be redundant.

Note that this is only because of the initial "Even". If the sentence were like:

> People who work with numbers forget this.

then it could just mean that people forget this when they happen to be working with numbers. We'd need to add "regularly" to qualify either the type of people or forgetting. But "even" already adds the implication that we're talking about a group that has a special relationship with working with numbers, we don't need "regularly" as well.

This version is more interesting:

> People who work with numbers regularly forget this.

If we take "regularly" as modifying "people who work with numbers", it suggests that these people tend to forget this, while people who only work with numbers occasionally do not. Grammatically this is possible, but it seems intuitively unlikely. So I'd still interpret this as "regularly forget".

If you really wanted to make "regularly" apply to "people who work with numbers", I'd rewrite it as:

> People who regularly work with numbers forget this.